# Как получить угол, на который нужно повернуть мэш, чтобы он смотрел в направлении других координат?

Tags: c++, математика, разработка-игр

У меня есть координаты мэша в пространстве `xMesh`, `yMesh`.
Так же у меня есть координаты точки `xTarget`, `yTarget`.

```
Vector2 MeshLocation(1,2);
Vector2 TargetLocation(3,4);
```

Как мне найти угол, на который надо повернуть мэш, чтобы он смотрел на `TargetLocation`?

Вот, что я пробовал:

```
ugol = (xMesh * xTarget + yMesh * yTarget) / (sqrt(xMesh * xMesh + yMesh * yMesh) * sqrt(xTarget * xTarget + yTarget * yTarget));
```

Но получатся какая то фигня и мэш просто крутится вокруг своей оси.

Comment: для того, что бы что то повернуть, нужно знать начальный вектор, то есть, знать, куда смотрит "меш" изначально

Comment: Мэш изначально смотрит в вправо и переменная angle имеет значение 0, кажется оно в радианах

Comment: - `tg a = dy/dx`

Comment: Не совсем понял, dy и dx это MeshVector и TargetVector?

Comment: вправо  - это по оси x? То есть, (1,0) ? и это все на плоскости?

Comment: @HashCode это дельты. xTaget - xMesh, yTarget - yMesh

Comment: Да, мэш изначально смотрит вправо, но нюанс в том, что поворот задается не вектором, в исходнике есть переменная float angle, ее значение изначально равно 0
При запуске игры этот мэш смотрит вправо, а камера смотрит на поле сверху вниз
У меня есть координаты точки, куда надо заставить мэш двигаться, координаты самого мэша тоже, по сути мне нужно получить правильный угол и повернуть мой мэш, что-бы он начал смотреть на маркер цели, никак не могу понять как это сделать...

Comment: Намекаю, намекаю. `angle = atan2(yTarget - yMesh, xTarget - xMesh)`

Comment: Так, сейчас попробую что то с этим нахимичить

Comment: Laukhin Andrey, Спасибо вам огромное вы мне очень помогли, дай бог вам здоровья))))